# While Loop stop with blank input

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

How can I make the while loop stop when the x input is blank instead of it stopping when the word 'stop' appears?

This is what I did but with 'stop'. However if  I change the condition to x!=' ', when I try to convert x into an int it breaks.

```
x=''
y=''
list=[]
while x!='stop':
    x=input('x input: ')
    y=int(input('y input: '))
    if x!='stop':
        list.append((int(x),y))
    
print('Stop')
print(list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
x=''
y=''
list=[]
while x!='stop':
    x=input('x input: ')
    y=int(input('y input: '))
    # break loop when x is empty string
    if x == '':
        break;
    if x!='stop':
        list.append((int(x),y))
    
    
print('Stop')
print(list)
```

`break` keyword *breaks the loop* if `x` is empty string. Validate variable `x` before casting it to `int`.

Comment: @bench You should accept the answer by clicking the grey tick under the vote sign. If you feel like, you can give an upvote as well. Helps the rep of the person who answered.

Comment: Just did! I forgot to do it cause it made me wait 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want to do.

```
x='x'  
y='y'  
list=[]  
while x!='':  
    x=input('x input: ')  
    if x!='':  
        y=int(input('y input: '))  
        list.append((int(x),y))  
    
print('Stop')  
print(list)
```